# Tomcat is running on port 8080, but unable to access remotely using IP address?

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, tcp

I have freshly installed apache-tomcat-7.0.62 on my server.
When i start tomcat it start with no errors, but when i want to access it using browser it says page is unavailable. I have used following command to check whether tomcat is running correctly or not :-

```
     netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

and following is the output : -

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19430/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8009            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19430/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19430/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -

following is the contents of **catalina.out**

```
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM               org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM    org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 7 2015 17:14:55 UTC
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM     org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.62.0
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Linux
  Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
  INFO: OS Version:            3.13.0-48-generic
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM      org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Architecture:          amd64
   Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM      org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b14
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation 
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.62
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-7.0.62
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: - Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat- 7.0.62/conf/logging.properties
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Command line argument: - Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses=true
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/ubuntu/apache- tomcat-7.0.62/endorsed
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM  org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/ubuntu/apache-     tomcat-7.0.62
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/ubuntu/apache- tomcat-7.0.62
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
 INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/ubuntu/apache-   tomcat-7.0.62/temp
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener  lifecycleEvent
  INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal     performance in production environments was not found on the   java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-  gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-  gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
 INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
 INFO: Initialization processed in 1060 ms
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService     startInternal
 INFO: Starting service Catalina
  Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   startInternal
 INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig  deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat- 7.0.62/webapps/ROOT
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig  deployDirectory
 INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache - tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/ROOT has finished in 805 ms
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig    deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat- 7.0.62/webapps/examples
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig  deployDirectory
 INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache-  tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/examples has finished in 611 ms
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig  deployDirectory
 INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-  7.0.62/webapps/host-manager
  Aug 28, 2015 7:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig   deployDirectory
 INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache- tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/host-manager has finished in 204 ms
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig  deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat    -7.0.62/webapps/manager
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig    deployDirectory
 INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache- tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/manager has finished in 107 ms
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig  deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache-tomcat-  7.0.62/webapps/docs
Aug 28, 2015 7:56:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig   deployDirectory
 INFO: Deployment of web application directory /home/ubuntu/apache-  tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/docs has finished in 115 ms
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
 INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
 INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
 Aug 28, 2015 7:56:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
 INFO: Server startup in 1960 ms
```

Following is the content of **server.xml** file

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" 
 useIPVHosts="true" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>


 <Host name="mining.knowaptitude.in"  appBase="mining_apps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>

    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: What exactly did happen when you try to access your remote ip ? And which context-path are you trying to reach ?

Comment: show your server.xml config file.

Comment: You tomcat only listen on localhost. change the server.xml to your external ip-address

Comment: i have tried to access tomcat by following link `http://54.149.233.194:8080/`. and also tried using `telnet 54.149.233.194 8080` it does not connect. but when i use `telnet localhost 8080` on remote computer (after login to server via ssh) it shows connected. @SercanOzdemir

Comment: As @thienkhoi-tran indicated in his address you have to set up a nat if you want to use your internet address. You also have to disable your firewall or add an exception for this port number if you want to access it from another computer.

Comment: my server IP is accessible remotely for 80 port (apache server) but not for 8080 port (tomcat) @ChristopheThiry

Comment: So one more thing, please check your Firewall. Checking step by step the connection from external network to your server. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you mr @thienkhoitran, it was firewall which prevent me to access remotely.Finally i am able to access it remotely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check if port 8080 is accessible from outside. port could be blocked. Check your firewall settings and open the port for http request.

Comment: I have checked using following command `nmap 54.149.233.194`  but not found  8080 port in port lists. what should i do to fixed it? @Azhar

Comment: I am using a custom port and that port is accessible externally. But when I call a specific service i.e. for example 225.125.888.115:628 I am getting errors on my console. But locally I am not getting any errors

Answer (score 2):

You have to setting NAT for your router to connect from the internet.
You don't need to do that if you connect from lan.
I checked and your port is closing.
Use this tool to check http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
Or http://www.canyouseeme.org/

Answer (score 2):

1. disable firewalld:

   ```
   # systemctl stop firewalld
   # systemctl disable firewalld
   ```
2. replace localhost with a valid IP that can be exposed externally in server.xml

Comment: Been searching for a while, finally stop firewalld helped! thanks.