# Tomcat access from external IP

Tags: tomcat, server, forwarding

I have next network: internet cable -> router -> server -> tomcat, installed on server.
Tomcat is working on port 8090.
I can access to tomcat from localhost:8090, but can't access external_ip_adress:8090.
Port forwarding is done.
For managing server, use RDP external_ip_adress:8090.
This is my server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
       <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8090" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
       useIPVHosts="true"
       resolveHosts="true" 

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>

  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

What I should do for access tomcat from external ip. Maybe another settings or another port forwarding. Please, help noob)

Comment: `useIPVHosts="true"`
 `resolveHosts="true"`

These two properties should do the trick - Did you restart your Tomcat / TomEE service after making this change?

Comment: yes, I restart.. and it doesnt work. To the point, firewall is off.

Comment: Can you add the following as well and restart? address="0.0.0.0" to the <Connector /> tag

Comment: it not working(

Comment: Check these, if it helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32266553/tomcat-is-running-on-port-8080-but-unable-to-access-remotely-using-ip-address & this -> https://serverfault.com/questions/98436/why-cant-i-access-tomcat-externally

Comment: thanks for your helping. But still not work.  Result of nmap:
PORT     STATE SERVICE
3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server
8090/tcp open  opsmessaging

Comment: If "router" is your home DSL router (or equivalent) then it's setup by default to not serve anything from within your network, and no configuration of Tomcat will help you. And, if that's your problem, this question is not programming related, but rather system administration. With the assumed home router I doubt that it hits the "professional" aspect of serverfault.com though. Not sure where to best migrate this question to.

Comment: @OlafKock I agree that this is not really a question for SO. Might [superuser](https://superuser.com/) be appropriate?

Comment: once check telnet to the server with port no, if working then there is an issue with configuration if not then try to turn off server firewall and give a try.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, identified these changes could help (Please give it a try, if you are still struggling with the same issue):

Making the following change, we will open access from other hosts:

- Edit 'CATALINA_HOME/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml'

  - We can disable the RemoteAddrValve value by commenting it out as shown below:

  > **< !--Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="127.\d+.\d+.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /-->**
- The same step has to be repeated for 'CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml' as well.

Hope this answers your question!